# String - first and last name in alphabetical with capital letter

Tags: c, string, algorithm, function, pointers

I need to arrange the names accordingly in alphabetical order. I managed to get the desired output. However, when I type the name with first cap, eg: Peter, the output is different.

EG input: `Peter Paul John Mary`

EG output: `First word = John, Last word = d`

But when I type with small letter, the output is perfect.

Here is my code:

```
void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last, int size);

int main() {
    char word[SIZE][40];
    char first[40], last[40];
    int i, size;

    printf("Enter size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d words: \n", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%s", word[i]);

    findMinMaxStr(word, first, last, size);
    printf("First word = %s, Last word = %s\n", first, last);
    return 0;
}

void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last, int size) {
    /* Write your program code here */
    int k, l;

    for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        if (strcmp(word[k], last) > 0) {
            strcpy(last, word[k]);
        } else
        if (strcmp(word[k], first) < 0) { 
            strcpy(first, word[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upper case letters are lexicographically less than lower case. Use `tolower` on everything to ignore the case.

Comment: maybe because `strcmp` is case sensitive?

Comment: But @EugeneSh. skylight reports that the input is only with Case letters: `Peter Paul John Mary`.

Comment: skylight, can you please provide a complete working minimal example? I wonder how you use `first` and `last` too.

Comment: You need to provide more code so that we can verify it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp` is case sensitive so "Peter" and "peter" are considered different. Instead you want to use `strcasecmp` as that will ignore the case of characters.

Comment: skylight reports that the input is only with Case letters: `Peter Paul John Mary`

Comment: @gsamaras that isn't what is in the question, it clearly has "But when i type with small letter, the output is perfect." in it.

Comment: this works. However when i enter one name, my first name returns ? and my last name return the input name. for eg: i enter peter, my first name is ? with a box and last name is peter @christurner

Comment: @skylight the problem is you've not shared enough of your code to identify where the problem is - how do you initialise `first` and `last` for example? Adding `*first='\0'; *last='\0'` at the start of `findMinMaxStr` would ensure they're at least empty strings to start with

Comment: Okay i have edited my code. please take a look.Thanks @ChrisTurner

Comment: @skylight yes, it's as expected - you're not initialising `first` or `last`

Comment: `strcasecmp` isn't standard C - it might not be available on non-POSIX systems.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your approach:

- You do not initialize `first`, nor `last`: comparing `word[i]` to an uninitialized array has undefined behavior.
- You only update `first` or `last`, but not both. If there is only one word, `first` **and** `last` should receive the only word.
- `strcmp()` is case sensitive. If you want to determine the first and last names in a case insensitive way, you must write more code. A simplistic approach can be achieved with `tolower()` from `<ctype.h>` but a complete solution requires in depth understanding of rules for collation of names, which is very complex and locale specific.

Here is a simplistic approach:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int strcasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    for (;;) {
        unsigned char c1 = tolower((unsigned char)*s1++);
        unsigned char c2 = tolower((unsigned char)*s2++);
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 < c2 ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (c1 == '\0') {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}           

void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last, int size) {
    int k;

    *first = *last = '\0';
    if (size > 0) {
        strcpy(first, word[0]);
        strcpy(last, word[0]);
        for (k = 1; k < size; k++) {
            if (strcasecmp(last, word[k]) < 0) {
                strcpy(last, word[k]);
            } else
            if (strcasecmp(first, word[k]) > 0) { 
                strcpy(first, word[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the presented code it is unclear how the arguments that correspond to the parameters `first` and `last` were declared and initialized.

But in any case the function should not do coping.

It can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   40

void findMinMaxStr( char word[][N], size_t size, char **first, char **last ) 
{
    *first = *last = word[0];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( strcmp( word[i], *first ) < 0 )
        {
            *first = word[i];
        }
        else if ( strcmp( *last, word[i] ) < 0 )
        {
            *last = word[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char word[][N] = { "Peter",  "Paul",  "John", "Mary" };
    char *first, *last;

    findMinMaxStr( word, sizeof( word ) / sizeof( *word ), &first, &last );

    printf( "First = \"%s\", last = \"%s\"\n", first, last );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
First = "John", last = "Peter"
```

Comment: i cant hardcode the names because the users have to enter how many names they want and type the name . for eg: enter size: 4; enter the 4 names: peter paul john mary; or enter size:2; enter the 2 names: peter paul @vlad

Comment: @skylight It is a demonstrative program that shows the function in action. You can write any code using the function.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `first` and `last` to `word[0]` and the start of your function, like this:

```
strcpy(first, word[0]);
strcpy(last, word[0]);
```

Then for an input of `Peter Paul john Mary`, you would get:

> First word = Mary, Last word = john

which is correct since upper case letters are lexicographically greater than the lower ones.

For an input of `Peter Paul John Mary`, you should get:

> First word = John, Last word = Peter

which is also correct.